# More space needed on /opt filesystem even after storage extension

Tags: filesystems, rhel, yum, rpm, storage

Trying to install an rpm with `yum localinstall` and I get:

```
Transaction Check Error:
installing package streamsets-datacollector-1.5.1.2-1.noarch 
needs 542MB on the /opt filesystem

Error Summary
-------------
Disk Requirements:
  At least 542MB more space needed on the /opt filesystem.
```

I checked free space with `df -h` and saw there were only 300MB available. So I did `lvextend -L +1G /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt`. Reran `df -h` and the change was reflected accurately. Tried installing once again and got the same error. I tried allocating even more space (3GB total free now, which is way bigger than this package should require) and I'm getting the same error with the same amount of required space missing.

Comment: Don't you have to run something like `resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt` (ext4) or `btrfs filesystem resize max /opt` (Btrfs) after the `lvextend` and before `df -h`

Comment: @Anthon OP probably did (or added the `-r` flag to lvextend), else it wouldn't show in `df`. But OP definitely needs to accurately report the steps...

Comment: @derobert Interestingly, I did neither of things and the change showed up in `df`. However I just ran what @Anthon suggested and it got things working. Thanks!

Comment: well then... @Anthon sounds like you should post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extending the logical volume, you still need to extend the filesystem that is on top of it.

For ext4:

```
resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt
```

For Btrfs:

```
btrfs filesystem resize max /opt
```

Or you could have originally added the `-r` option, as @derobert suggested. From the `lvextend` man page:

```
-r, --resizefs
      Resize underlying filesystem together with  the  logical  volume
      using fsadm(8).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lvextend -rL +1G /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt` to extend and resize automatically.

In case you don't use `-r` you have to check which FS you have and resize accordingly.

Manual resize :

1. For xfs: `xfs_growfs`
2. For ext2,3,4 : `resize2fs`